# generate price scenarios in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of variable `price` changes:

```py
price = 1000
changes = [0, -0.5, +0.5, -1, 1]
# change means new_price = old_price * (1 + change)
```

I need a list that shows how `price` will change as a result of several consecutive changes; for example, this is what it looks like for 2 consecutive changes:

```py
[1000, 1000, 1000]
[1000, 1000, 500]
[1000, 1000, 1500]
[1000, 1000, 0]
[1000, 1000, 2000]

[1000, 500, 500]
[1000, 500, 250]
[1000, 500, 750]
[1000, 500, 0]
[1000, 500, 1000]

[1000, 1500, 1500]
[1000, 1500, 750]
[1000, 1500, 2250]
[1000, 1500, 0]
[1000, 1500, 3000]

[1000, 0, 0]
[1000, 0, 0]
[1000, 0, 0]
[1000, 0, 0]
[1000, 0, 0]

[1000, 2000, 2000]
[1000, 2000, 1000]
[1000, 2000, 3000]
[1000, 2000, 0]
[1000, 2000, 4000]
```

The `numpy` library is allowed to be used.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: You say its the old price multiplied by `1+change`, but then `0 -> 2000` when it's multiplied by 2. Also, I fail to see why there are lists of 3 elements and why there are 5 sections of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast the calculation repeatedly, then broadcast the results to each other, and finally move the axis:

```
>>> changes = np.array([0, -0.5, +0.5, -1, 1])
>>> price = np.array(1000)
>>> prices = [price]
>>> times = 2
>>> for _ in range(times):
...     prices.append(prices[-1][..., None] * (changes + 1))
...
>>> shape = prices[-1].shape
>>> ar = np.array([np.broadcast_to(a[(...,) + (None,) * (times - i)], shape) for i, a in enumerate(prices)])
>>> np.moveaxis(ar, 0, -1)
array([[[1000., 1000., 1000.],
        [1000., 1000.,  500.],
        [1000., 1000., 1500.],
        [1000., 1000.,    0.],
        [1000., 1000., 2000.]],

       [[1000.,  500.,  500.],
        [1000.,  500.,  250.],
        [1000.,  500.,  750.],
        [1000.,  500.,    0.],
        [1000.,  500., 1000.]],

       [[1000., 1500., 1500.],
        [1000., 1500.,  750.],
        [1000., 1500., 2250.],
        [1000., 1500.,    0.],
        [1000., 1500., 3000.]],

       [[1000.,    0.,    0.],
        [1000.,    0.,    0.],
        [1000.,    0.,    0.],
        [1000.,    0.,    0.],
        [1000.,    0.,    0.]],

       [[1000., 2000., 2000.],
        [1000., 2000., 1000.],
        [1000., 2000., 3000.],
        [1000., 2000.,    0.],
        [1000., 2000., 4000.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks complicated but matrixes makes it easy to solve. There are several keys to undesrstand in order to solve the problem.

Lets take the following matrix:

```
[1000, 1000, 1000] <- list_of_changes
[1000, 1000, 500]  <- list_of_changes
[1000, 1000, 1500] <- list_of_changes
[1000, 1000, 0]    <- list_of_changes
[1000, 1000, 2000] <- list_of_changes
```

Every list of changes can be divided into 3 parts: `index0`, `index1`, `rest_of_indexes`.

1. The final matrix will always have 3 axises
2. `index0` will always be equal to `price`
3. `index1` will always be the change from `price` by index of `axis0` from `changes`
4. `rest_of_indexes` can be calculated buy iteretive process like the following examples

change_mat[0, :, 2] =

```
[1000]   [0]
[1000]   [-0.5]
[1000] * [+0.5]
[1000]   [-1]
[1000]   [1]
```

change_mat[1, :, 2] =

```
[500]   [0]
[500]   [-0.5]
[500] * [+0.5]
[500]   [-1]
[500]   [1]
```

This should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np


price = 1000
changes = np.array([0, -0.5, 0.5, -1, 1])

combinations = 2

change_mat = np.zeros((len(changes), len(changes), combinations + 1))

change_mat[:, :, 0] = price

for axis0 in range(len(changes)):
    change_mat[axis0, :, 1] = change_mat[axis0, :, 0] * (1 + changes[axis0])

for combination in range(combinations-1):
    change_mat[:, :, combination+2] = change_mat[:, :, combination+1] * (1 + changes)
```

Comment: unfortunately wrong, for example take the example of 3 consecutive changes: there will be no `[1000 1000 1000 500]` path although it should be